# Properly hiding content from both keyboard and screen reader

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, section508

We have a modal on a page that, when hidden, we want to **not** have keyboard users be able to tab into the content, nor have screen readers read.

To handle that, on the parent DIV, I've set up so that, when hidden, it has the following:

```
<div aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
    [child HTML/content]
<div>
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working. You can still tab into the content and the content is read (at least via Chrome and using VoiceOver).

Ideall, we'd also set `display: none`-- which I may be able to do -- but at the moment we're dependant on some CSS transition animations so would need to set that programmatically after animation.

Prior to going that route, however, is there anything I am missing from my initial understanding that aria-hidden and the tabindex should be taking care of the issue?

Comment: I did answer this but realised there is a little more info needed to give a complete answer. **1. What content is inside the containing div** and **2. how long is your transition to hide the div.** (as you may have to manage focus if the transition is long enough for someone to tab into the div that is being hidden). `tabindex="-1"` will not remove the ability to focus children so the short answer is that you need to add `tabindex="-1"` to all children that can receive focus if you want to remove them from the tab order (or if they are inputs add `disabled` to them)

Comment: @GrahamRitchie that's a good bit of info on the tabindex not working with children. In your opinion, though, should aria-hidden be working as I think it should? As for the transition, yes, it's possible someone could tab into it, but that's an edge case I'm not too worried about for now. At the moment, I'm leaning towards the good ol' hacky setTimeout to set it to display: none after minimizing animation ends.

Comment: display:none works everywhere, is very simple, and is probably the most correct semantically speaking. Stop wondering, keep it simple and stupid.

Comment: @QuentinC well, simple is relative. In this case, we're dealing with having to set it after some CSS transitions have already happened. Not a huge deal, but not a simple CSS update in that sense. Instead we have to update the angular side of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer

Using `display:none` without a transition would be the best option and would negate the need for `aria-hidden`.

If you are required to have a transition then do the transition and then set the `display: none` property after the transition.

Be careful for lost focus though if you transition is over 100ms, you have to do a lot of focus management to account for the delay in setting `display:none`.

### Longer Answer

`aria-hidden="true"` removes an item and its children from the accessibility tree. However it does not stop children that can receive focus (i.e. an `<input>`) from receiving focus.

`tabindex="-1"` will not remove focus from children elements that are already focusable.

The simplest way to solve all problems would be to remove the transition and simply toggle the display property. This not only solves your focus problem but it also removes the need for `aria-hidden`, making things simpler.

With that being said a transition may be part of your spec and unavoidable. If that is the case there are a few things to consider.

In our discussions in the comments and within your question you mentioned using `setTimeout` to set the display property to none after the transition has completed.

There is an issue with this approach depending on your design.

If the next tab stop is within the area that is being hidden it is feasible that during the transition someone may navigate to an element within the area that is about to be hidden.

If this were to happen focus on the page would be lost. Depending on the browser this could result in focus returning to the top of the page. This is something that would be highly frustrating and also probably constitute a fail under logical tab order / robustness in WCAG principles.

#### What would be the best way to achieve an animation on hide?

Because of the focus issue I would recommend the following process for hiding the content with a transition:-

1. The second the button / code that causes the area to be hidden is activated (pre fade-out) set `tabindex="-1"` on all interactive elements within the `<div>` that is to be hidden (or if they are inputs set the `disabled` attribute).
2. Start the transition by whatever means you are using (i.e. add the class to the item that will trigger the transition).
3. After the transition is complete set the `display: none` on the item.
4. Do the exact opposite if you wish to make the `<div>` visible again.

By doing this you ensure that nobody can accidentally tab into the div and lose focus. This helps everyone who relies on keyboard for navigation, not just screen reader users.

A very rough example of how to achieve this is below. It can be reused based on an ID of a container so hopefully will give you a good starting place to write something a little more robust (and less ugly! hehe)

I have added comments to explain as best I can. I have set the transition to 2 seconds so you can inspect and see the order of things.

**Finally I have included some CSS and JS to account for people who have indicated they prefer reduced motion due to motion sensitivity. In this case the animation time is set to 0.**

#### Rough example accounting for hiding items to manage tabindex and restoring tabindex if made visible again.

```js
var content = document.getElementById('contentDiv');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn_toggle');
var animationDelay = 2000;

//We should account for people with vestibular motion disorders etc. if they have indicated they prefer reduced motion. We set the animation time to 0 seconds.
var motionQuery = matchMedia('(prefers-reduced-motion)');
function handleReduceMotionChanged() {
  if (motionQuery.matches) {
    animationDelay = 0;
  } else { 
    animationDelay = 2000;
  }
}
motionQuery.addListener(handleReduceMotionChanged);
handleReduceMotionChanged();



//the main function for setting the tabindex to -1 for all children of a parent with given ID (and reversing the process)
function hideOrShowAllInteractiveItems(parentDivID){  
  //a list of selectors for all focusable elements.
  var focusableItems = ['a[href]', 'area[href]', 'input:not([disabled])', 'select:not([disabled])', 'textarea:not([disabled])', 'button:not([disabled])', '[tabindex]:not([disabled])', '[contenteditable=true]:not([disabled])'];
  
  //build a query string that targets the parent div ID and all children elements that are in our focusable items list.
  var queryString = "";
  for (i = 0, leni = focusableItems.length; i < leni; i++) {
    queryString += "#" + parentDivID + " " + focusableItems[i] + ", ";
  }
  queryString = queryString.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
      
  var focusableElements = document.querySelectorAll(queryString);      
  for (j = 0, lenj = focusableElements.length; j < lenj; j++) {
            
    var el = focusableElements[j];
    if(!el.hasAttribute('data-modified')){ // we use the 'data-modified' attribute to track all items that we have applied a tabindex to (as we can't use tabindex itself).
            
      // we haven't modified this element so we grab the tabindex if it has one and store it for use later when we want to restore.
      if(el.hasAttribute('tabindex')){
        el.setAttribute('data-oldTabIndex', el.getAttribute('tabindex'));
      }
              
      el.setAttribute('data-modified', true);
      el.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1'); // add `tabindex="-1"` to all items to remove them from the focus order.
              
    }else{
      //we have modified this item so we want to revert it back to the original state it was in.
      el.removeAttribute('tabindex');
      if(el.hasAttribute('data-oldtabindex')){
        el.setAttribute('tabindex', el.getAttribute('data-oldtabindex'));
        el.removeAttribute('data-oldtabindex');
      }
      el.removeAttribute('data-modified');
    }
  }
}



btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  contentDiv.className = contentDiv.className !== 'show' ? 'show' : 'hide';
  if (contentDiv.className === 'show') {
     content.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);
    setTimeout(function(){
      contentDiv.style.display = 'block';
      hideOrShowAllInteractiveItems('contentDiv');
    },0); 
  }
  if (contentDiv.className === 'hide') {
      content.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);
      hideOrShowAllInteractiveItems('contentDiv');
    setTimeout(function(){
      contentDiv.style.display = 'none';
    },animationDelay); //using the animation delay set based on the users preferences.
  }
});
```

```css
@keyframes in {
  0% { transform: scale(0); opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;  }
  100% { transform: scale(1); opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }
}

@keyframes out {
  0% { transform: scale(1); opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }
  100% { transform: scale(0); opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;  }
}

#contentDiv {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#contentDiv.show {
  animation: in 2s ease both;
}

#contentDiv.hide {
  animation: out 2s ease both;
}


/*****We should account for people with vestibular motion disorders etc. if they have indicated they prefer reduced motion. ***/
@media (prefers-reduced-motion) {
  #contentDiv.show,
  #contentDiv.hide{
    animation: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="contentDiv" class="show">
  <p>Some information to be hidden</p>
  <input />
  <button>a button</button>
  <button tabindex="1">a button with a positive tabindex that needs restoring</button>
</div>

<button id="btn_toggle"> Hide Div </button>
```

Comment: A VERY nice and thorough answer! Thank you. And excellent point on dealing with the 'fast tabbing' with the setTimeout option.

Comment: Not a problem I am glad it was useful, also pay attention to the "prefers-reduced-motion" part, as I glossed over that bit, but it is really useful for people with motion sensitivity / anxiety etc. Good luck with the project :-)

Answer (score 2):

If implementing the solution provided by Graham Ritchie earlier is not possible, you'll need to make sure that:

1. **all** focusable children of the modal receive `tabindex="-1"` when the modal is hidden and
2. both the `aria-hidden` is removed from the parent (set to `false`) and all these focusable children have `tabindex` removed.

**Note:** avoid using a positive value for `tabindex` (i.e. `tabindex="1"`) as it will mess with the focus order of the page (which usually follows the order of the DOM and should follow the reading order of the page). The best is to only use `tabindex="0"` to add an element in the natural focus order and `tabindex="-1"` to remove it from the focus order (but still be able to use JavaScript `.focus()` method on it, if needed).

Comment: Upvote for the note on positive `tabindex` being a bad idea, I included that in my example without my normal disclaimer that it should not be used and it was included for completeness.