# Alternatives for tabindex

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

I need an alternative way to disable tab behavior for a focusable element. This behavior is specifically for screen readers, so `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` wouldn't work for me.

I cannot use tabindex because of a particularity of the environment that overrides the tabindex, so everytime I set `tabindex="-1"`, it gets overriden for `tabindex="0"`. I'm looking for a quick solution for this as this particularity is out of my reach at this moment.

Comment: I hate to say it but fix the environment is your best option by a mile, manually managing focus via JavaScript is a real pain in the rear end and not very robust (and would normally be managed by adding `tabindex="-1"` anyway even if done via JS). You would have to intercept focus and look to see if an item has a particular identifier that marks it as non-focusable, then find the next focusable item and instantly focus that item. You would then have to reverse the process incase someone did `shift` + `tab`. What environment is this as that sounds like a fault that may have a fix somewhere.

Comment: Additionally trying to disable something specifically for screen readers raises a few red flags so a better understanding of what you are trying to achieve may reveal a better solution. A fiddle or explanation would be great as to why you need this behaviour. As a final note, adding `tabindex="-1"` will **NOT** hide things from screen readers as generally you navigate by headings, links, regions etc. when using a screen reader. All it does is stop people who rely on keyboard but not a screen reader from accessing it (i.e. someone with dexterity / mobility issues who cant use a mouse)

Comment: To hide something from a screen reader you use `aria-hidden="true"`, but you would still have your focus issue to contend with.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it helped a lot. As I can't fix the environment at this moment, I'll be using the `onfocus` just for a quick and temporary solution. Just to clarify, I was reviewing the issue and it really isn't related to screen readers, but `tab` behaviour only. It happened because the user who provided this feedback was using a screen reader, there so navigating using `tab`.

Comment: If this strange behaviour is back-end related you could try using JavaScript to add the `tabindex="-1"` on page load perhaps? A bit hacky but still better than trying to manage focus I promise! You could take some inspiration from this answer I gave https://stackoverflow.com/a/63730747/2702894 for things like the CSS selector to grab all focusable items. Good luck with it, I sympathise with restrictions of strange systems! :-)